# Disable Wordpress URL auto Redirect

Tags: redirect, urls, wp-redirect

Wordpress auto redirect http://example.com?lang=fa to http://example.com/?lang=fa how to stop that?

Comment: Are you sure WP is doing that and not your browser? Those URLs are the same, and the `/?` version is more correct

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done, and it isn't WordPress, it isn't even a redirect.

example.com?foo=bar isn't a real URL, so the browser corrects it to example.com/?foo=bar before it's sent out, no redirection happens

Comment: I can not agree with you. The WordPress ends the addresses with a slash, and when there is no trailing slash in the address, it redirects. `example.com/pane_name` will be redirected to `example.com/page_name/`, and `example.com/foo?paged=2` to `example.com/foo/?paged=2`. In both cases a `HTTP 301` header is sent.

Comment: Both those URLs mean the same thing though, this isn't being done for SEO purposes is it?

Comment: Probably WordPress is trying to maintain linking consistency, it's possible that for SEO, but this is not my field. I meant only that it is not the browser changes address, and that redirection, however, takes place.

Comment: im moving from another cms to wordpress so its for seo.wordpress just redirect firstpage so this link `example.com/foo?paged=2` not redirecting

Comment: So that case wouldn't be affected, it's only the trailing slash on the very end that matters, e.g. `/foo` vs `/foo/` that Google pays attention to, see https://www.seroundtable.com/google-trailing-slashes-url-24943.html